# Open Balls in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

The Question is

> Is $\mathbb{R}$ an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric?

I think no. Because we need to select a radius $r\in     \mathbb{R}$   such that $B_{r}\left(p\right)$ for some $p\in  \mathbb{R}$ Which is, for obvious reasons impossible.

Comment: It is indeed obvious, just like it is obvious that the answer would be "yes" if the metric were $\arctan\lvert x-y\rvert$  instead of the usual one.

Comment: @saucy I didn't get you.

Comment: If you are learning analysis, you need to write a formal proof of this fact. To do this, argue by contradiction - suppose you have an r (a positive real number, not any real number like you wrote), and a p. Then show there must be some real number q that is not in $B_r(p)$. You can write an explicit formula for such a q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think You are right .
As Open ball concept is to show something bounded quantity.
As Lorenzo Sir Said In Comment .
On contrary assume $\mathbb R $ is open ball That means there $\mathbb R=B(x,r) $ for some $x,r\in R$ [As you have choosen $R $ as space ] That means $\mathbb R=(x-r,x+r) $ Clearly $x-r-1\notin R $ Hence Our Assumption is  wrong.
Hence R cannot be Open ball